# NSString instance reports its class as NSCFString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class, nsstring, class-cluster

My objective here is really simple -- I'm trying to set an `NSString` to some test data, then return the class, which should be `NSString`. Here's my code:

```
NSString* stringer = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test"];
NSLog(@"%@", [stringer class]);
```

The log says that the class is `NSCFString`, not `NSString`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

NSString is really a container class for different types of string objects. Generally an NSString constructor *does* return an object that is actually of type NSCFString, which is a thin wrapper around the Core Foundation CFString struct.

Answer (score 25):

NSString is a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/chapter_3_section_9.html), along with other Foundation types such as NSNumber and NSArray:

> Class clusters are a design pattern
>   that the Foundation framework makes
>   extensive use of. Class clusters group
>   a number of private, concrete
>   subclasses under a public, abstract
>   superclass. The grouping of classes in
>   this way simplifies the publicly
>   visible architecture of an
>   object-oriented framework without
>   reducing its functional richness.
>   Class clusters are based on the
>   Abstract Factory design pattern
>   discussed in “Cocoa Design Patterns.”

Comment: Why did Apple not follow this approach for NSOrderedSet?  A NSOrderedSet behaves exactly like a NSArray at the interface level, yet they made a independent class for it.