# Why does NSString respond to appendString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I was playing with the respondsToSelector method in Objective-C on MacOS-X 10.6.7 and Xcode 4.0.2, to identify if an object would respond to certain messages. According to the manuals, NSString should not respond to appendString: while NSMutableString should. Here's the piece of code which tests it:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init];

    if ([myString respondsToSelector:@selector(appendString:)]) {
        NSLog(@"myString responds to appendString:");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"myString doesn't respond to appendString:");
    }

    // do stuff with myString

    [myString release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the output:

```
Class02[10241:903] myString responds to appendString:
```

I'd sort of expected the opposite. How does an NSString object respond to appendString: ? What's going on here that I'm missing ?

Comment: If you sent it a real `appendString:` message does anything blow up?

Comment: Yes: `Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:`.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes it blows up, but isn't that the point of using the `respondsToSelector:` method, to check it won't blow up before sending it a real `appendString:` message?

Comment: Oh my, was hitting a wall with why a NSString was saying it was mutable at run time and then would blow up - WTF Apple, this is sooo bad.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: That string is of type `NSCFString`, a class that inherits from `NSMutableString`, hence it responds to the selectors for the methods declared in `NSMutableString`, including superclasses.

Not so short answer: Foundation strings are toll-free bridged with Core Foundation strings. Developers use the opaque types `CFStringRef` (bridged with `NSString`) and `CFMutableStringRef` (bridged with `NSMutableString`) to refer to these strings so, at first glance, there are two different types of strings: immutable and mutable.

From a Core Foundation internal implementation perspective, there’s a private type called `struct __CFString`. This private type keeps a bit field that stores, amongst other information, whether the string is mutable or immutable. Having a single type simplifies implementation since many functions are shared by both immutable and mutable strings.

Whenever a Core Foundation function that operates on mutable strings is called, it first reads that bit field and checks whether the string is mutable or immutable. If the argument is supposed to be a mutable string but it in fact isn’t, the function returns an error (e.g. `_CFStringErrNotMutable`) or fails an assertion (e.g. `__CFAssertIsStringAndMutable(cf)`).

At any rate, these are implementation details, and they might change in the future. The fact that `NSString` doesn’t declare `-appendString:` doesn’t mean that every `NSString` instance doesn’t respond to the corresponding selector — think [substitutability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The same situation applies to other mutable/immutable classes such as `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`. From the developer perspective, the important thing is that the object that’s been returned is of a type that matches the return type — it could be the type itself or any subtype of that type. Class clusters make this a tad more convoluted but the situation is not restricted to class clusters per se.

In summary, you can only expect that a method returns an object whose type belongs to the hierarchy (i.e., either the type itself or a subtype) of the type for the return value. Unfortunately, this means that you cannot check whether a Foundation object is mutable or not. But then again, do you really need this check?

---

You can use the `CFShowStr()` function to get information from a string. In the example in your question, add

```
CFShowStr((CFStringRef)myString);
```

You should get an output similar to:

```
Length 0
IsEightBit 1
HasLengthByte 0
HasNullByte 1
InlineContents 0
Allocator SystemDefault
Mutable 0
Contents 0x0
```

where

```
Mutable 0
```

means that the string is in fact immutable.

Answer (score 2):

This probably has to do with the implementation. `NSString` is a class cluster, which means that `NSString` is just a public interface and the actual implementing class is different ([see what the `class` message gives you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393873)).

And at the same time `NSString` is also toll-free bridged to `CFString`, meaning that you can switch before those two types freely just by casting:

```
NSString *one = @"foo";
CFStringRef two = (CFStringRef)one; // valid cast
```

When you create a new string you really get a `NSCFString` back, a thin wrapper around `CFString`. And the point is that when you create a new mutable string, you also get an instance of `NSCFString`.

```
Class one = [[NSString string] class]; // NSCFString
Class two = [[NSMutableString string] class]; // NSCFString
```

I guess this was convenient from the implementation point of view – both `NSString` and `NSMutableString` can be backed by a common class (= less code duplication) and this class makes sure you don’t violate the immutability:

```
// “Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:”
[[NSString string] appendString:@"foo"];
```

There’s a lot of guess work in this answer and I don’t really understand the stuff, let’s hope somebody knows better.

Answer (score 1):

You should not make assumptions about a method being *not* there. That method might be used internally or for whatever reason it exists. Technically, it's just private API.

You only have a contract to the public declarations (*docs*), and they don't show that message. So be prepared to get into trouble rather quickly if you use other features.

Comment: Agreed, but one could argue that supporting a method only to throw an exception is weird. It goes against duck typing – this particular thing walks like a duck, but isn’t really a duck.

Comment: @zoul: I've seen `NotImplementedException`s thrown all over the place in other languages. I wouldn't be surprised if something similar happened here. But your answer seems more sensible.