# NSString may not respond to append string

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have a `NSMutableString` and I am trying to use `appendString` method. Though it works fine but every time I use it, I receive a warning **NSString may not respond to append string**. This is my code :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    [soapResults appendString: string];        //soapResults is an NSMutableString in .h
}
```

I know I am getting this warning because of **NSString string** but how to remove this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.soapResults=(NSMutableString *)[self.soapResults stringByAppendingString:string];

or

soapResults=(NSMutableString *)[soapResults stringByAppendingString:string];
```

OR

```
self.soapResults=(NSMutableString *)[[self.soapResults stringByAppendingString:string] mutableCopy];

    //    or

soapResults=(NSMutableString *)[[soapResults stringByAppendingString:string] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: stringByAppendingString which will return NSString. so we have to manually specify NSMutableString*

Comment: take a look at this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894910/why-does-nsstring-respond-to-appendstring

Comment: @nitish u r welcome.but be responsive to others while they ask or request.thanks again.have a nice day.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment (that I deleted since): I haven't seen the "mutableCopy" in your code (it was offscreen and had no scrollbar to tell me). Obviously with ```mutableCopy``` your code works (even if it generates useless allocations to do this way -- generating a new NSString, then a mutableCopy of it -- than to modify an existing NSMutableString)

Comment: @AliSoftware all of us not genius in Objective c.but trying to do...that's it.so dont say sorry!!!.u rocks

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure `soapResults` **is** actually an `NSMutableString`, and only have a **warning**, then simply cast it before calling `appendString:` to it :

```
[(NSMutableString*)soapResults appendString: string];
```

If you declared `soapResults` as an NSMutableString but in fact affected an `NSString` to it, then you probably don't have a warning, but will have a runtime error on execution.

*If `soapResults` is an `NSString` (either because you declared it so or because you affected an `NSString` to it), you may instead create a new `NSString` by appending string to it, then create a `mutableCopy` from it... but I **don't** recommend this as it will generate useless allocations (and `NSMutableString` is better to avoid this)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. But as AppleVijay posted the correct answer earlier I must accept his answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply, at this point in the code soapResults is not a `NSMutableString`.  Perhaps somewhere else in the code it is inadvertently replaced with a `NSString`.

As an aside, `NSString` is really an `NSMutableString` code-wise even though `NSMutableString` is a subclass of `NSString`.  This might help explain what is happening in the code.

Still, casting an `NSString` to an `NSMutableString` is not a good idea, what really needs to be done is find where it is becoming an `NSString` and fix that.