# Getting an NSString from an NSCFString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, casting

I read around S.O and did Google this a fair bit but I wasn't able to find an answer to my problem...

I have an `NSDictionary` which is returning `NSCFString's` and what I need is an NSString so that I can use its doubleValue function. I can't for the life of me figure out how to turn my `NSCFString`'s into `NSString`s. I've tried the following with no success:

```
NSString* lng_coord = (NSString*)[dict objectForKey:key];
            if ([lng_coord class] == [NSString class])
                NSLog(@"lng coord is an exact match with NSString class");
            else {
                NSLog(@"lng coord doesn't match NSString class");
                NSLog(@"The class of lng_coord is %@", [[dict objectForKey:key] class]);
            }
            NSLog(@"%@", lng_coord);
            [CelebsAnnotation setLongitude:[lng_coord doubleValue]];
```

And this is the output from console:

```
lng coord doesn't match NSString class
The class of lng_coord is NSCFString
49.2796758
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obj C NSString returning class NSCFString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393873/obj-c-nsstring-returning-class-nscfstring)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSCFString` is a private subclass of `NSString`, you can just use it as one.

Because of such patterns like [class clusters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34), you shouldn't directly compare the classes here - use [`-isKindOfClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBFBDJ) instead:

```
if ([lng_coord isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // ...
```

Comment: @11684: Any more details? Have you checked that you are actually dealing with NSCFStrings?