# Declared vs Actual type, in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I was debugging something in my code and realized that the following compiles

```
NSMutableSet *s = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Card *c = [[Card alloc] init];

[s addObject:c];
[s addObject:c];
[s addObject:c];

NSLog(@"Set now contains %d cards ", [s count]); //Prints 3
```

But the declared type is a Set here .. why are duplicates allowed? Why does this compiles at all?

Comment: Are you really allocating the Set as an Array, in your first line, or was this a typo?

Comment: Of course this is a typo, but the question is, why does this compile at all?

Comment: I am curious about this as well. So I ran a quick test. For the same code, I got 1 as output. How did you get 3? It's true that set won't store duplicate values, but it doesn't necessarily mean you can't add duplicate value into it. It's a matter of logic "error" and thus compiler won't complain.

Comment: @James: what Luiz is asking is whether there's a typo in your sample (i.e. the sample is different from the code you ran), not whether the actual code had a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` returns type `id`, this is standard for Objective-C to return type `id`. In many cases the actual returned type depends on the class implementation, many Apple supplied classes are class clusters and return a different type. A common example of this is `NSString` which *usually* returns an instance of the class `NSCFString`.

It is important to be careful about matching class names.

Also see the answer by [Marc Charbonneau here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394004/451475)

Comment: Thank you. Makes perfect sense

Answer (score 2):

`[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` returns `id` as @CocoaFu mentioned.  You are assigning it to a pointer that you declared as `NSMutableSet` which is acceptable because of the returned `id`.  Like most other languages, just because you declared it to be an `NSMutableSet` does not make it one.

Since both `NSMutableSet` and `NSMutableArray` have a method called `-addObject:` there is no warning from the compiler about an unknown method being called.

There is no specific error in your code other than your pointer, as declared, is inaccurate.